# CSS: Shrink element to containing (wrappable) text

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML element containing text:

```html
<h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
```

1. Its width should be limited to a certain maximum.
2. The text should be split into two lines if necessary.
3. The text should not be split if it fits in a single line.
4. The width should be only as big as required by the containing text.

This basic CSS code conforms to all rules except the last rule if the text is split into two lines:

```css
h2 {
  max-width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

This one conforms to all rules except the third:

```css
h2 {
  max-width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: min-content;
}
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: It would be easier to ask if you provide some detail on how it's embedded (in which structure) because depending on that flex or grid might be suitable

Comment: you cannot have the (4) when the text split in two lines

Comment: What, if you change `width: min-content;` to `width: fit-content;`? I'm not sure, if this fulfills all 4 points. Sorry, can't test it right now.

Comment: @Ferris: I’ve already tried this. `width: fit-content;` also violates rule 4 by taking up the maximum space when the text is split into more than one line.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content

Comment: @OuttaSpaceTime: I can change the context to whatever needed. If we can find a solution using a wrapper around the h2 element, that’s also fine. (But I would like to avoid wrapping the single words of the text.)